# Ember CLI Addons won't show up in browser

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I got big hopes when I heard of package-managing for Ember.js. After several tries I'm quite disappointed. Maybe I got something wrong. Lately I'm not even getting one specific addon to work.

So in docs there are always command lines like:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-components
```

So I did that. But nothing worked. Still wanna-have component `em-modal` is not available in my Ember App.

I fiddled around with bower install. Nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong? In every doc of every plugin installing seems super easy, but not for me?

Comment: ember-cli-components is over 2 years old, components are now part of ember-master. Please use recent plugins and "ember install" instead of "npm install".

Comment: where can I find ember-master? is bootstrap-modal also included?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Components are now official part of Ember and do not require a plugin anymore. For bootstrap (modal) see http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/getting-started/

Comment: so what do I do when a plugin is not available as Ember Addon but for bower. For example video.js. I could install it with npm and bower. nothing helped for me. also adding the bower path to ember-cli-build doesn't work.

Comment: Does http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#managing-dependencies help?